# What should be the sense to use strict comparison to this specific string: 'final'

Tags: javascript

In a code review that I was doing to a coworker, I said that here:

```
if (someValue === 'final'){
```

There is no sense to use strict comparison because the only way to pass it as true is with other string value equals to final.

I think that it is enough:

```
if (someValue == 'final'){
```

His argument is that an object could have a toString method that returns that string but strictly it does not have the same datatype.

While that is true, as a computer(that are not intelligent as human), in the other hand, there is not sense, as at the end of the way the only way to pass this as true is with a string equals to final. This was his sample code:

```
Test = function(){}
Test.prototype.toString = function () { return 'final'; }
var disagreeDaniel = new Test();
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = (disagreeDaniel == 'final');
```

So my point here guys, is that I need you get better explanation to him why there is not sense of the strict comparison on a fixed strict like 'final' because there is no way to pass it as positive with a value different than 'final'.(his example at the end return the string)

For me strict comparison is useful for booleans, nulls, undefined, zero, where those could pass all as false in some cases. I want to hear your opinions.

**====== Update ==========**

It is easy to identify that people does not read. My question was the sense of use === to compare to 'final'. I got a lot of explanations of things nothing to do. For compare to null, false, zero etc, I said that I used === for THOSE cases but not for long strings. but people tried to explained me about null, false, zero, etc. The verdict until now is that there is not a SOLID argument(there are some good ones but not solid) that demonstrate why using === for compare to 'final' should be better than use ==(read again, is just this use case, I'm talking about one specific use case).

I also spoke with my coworker, I gave him the +1 to the code. I do not have problems with ===, my problem never had to use it, my point always was and is, and will be, what should be the **sense**, and looks like it would be a question with nevertheless answer.

ps. other thing that I learned time ago, is to never be aggressive with other opinions; "technical topics" for several programmers, are like religion for religious(and some guys here just remembered me it).

ps2. I marked as solved to be democratic, I do not want to demonstrate anything, just thought this site is for good discussions, and I got that. :D

Comment: Use === for consistency. You don't want to always have to think about edge cases. Consistency in code is super important, much more than the extra "="

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand your objection to using triple equals. I've run your coworkers's code and it outputs `true`. That would indicate he is right and a malicious or careless type could pass the condition despite not being a string.

Comment: It is not objections, everything here is regarding the sense. There are not any use case where == should be a problem. (in this specific case 'final'). While also === is not an issue, I liked also to have common sense, is what differs us from a computer.

Comment: @DanielAranda While I agree with Esailija's standpoint as I've stated in my answer before, I find the notion of someone overriding toString of an object for the purpose of it being equal `final` absurd. We should not have to code to cater this sort of behavior. The fact `==` can be 'tricked' to accept an object as equal to the string `final` is an extremely poor argument against it IMHO where cognitive load and consistency in code are both much much better arguments.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum now you are following my point. :)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, for example `typeof x == "string"` is functionally exactly the same as `typeof x === "string"`.

However, `x == " "`, is not even remotely the same as `x === " "` since a string that is full of whitespace coerces towards `0` and `0 == " " //true` or `false == " " //true` .

`===` is written because the extra cognitive load required to judge each scenario individually for possible one character savings is just not worth it. I bet you that you or most programmers did not even know about the whitespace strings. Your brain needs to confirm that `== "final"` is not in any corner case, and only then you can proceed writing it.

You can wake me up the middle of the night and I will recite all the `==` rules and corner cases by heart, but that doesn't mean I will want to go through to them **every time** an equality comparison is needed.

A notable exception is `== null` which should be memorized as "undefined or null" and is even specially supported by jshint which otherwise enforces `===`.

---

And wait, there is more. From [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

> ECMAScript implementations must recognise all of the white space characters defined in Unicode 3.0. Later editions of the Unicode Standard may define other white space characters. ECMAScript implementations may recognise white space characters from later editions of the Unicode Standard

That implies the operation `==` is *implementation defined* for comparisons of string and boolean/object/number

For example:

```
function equals( x ) {
    return x == "\ufeff\ufeff";
}
alert(equals(0));
```

[Gives `true` on Firefox but `false` on Chrome.](http://jsfiddle.net/4nYjw/)

Comment: +1, When is == ok in code? Are there times where it's useful?

Comment: "extra cognitive load required to judge each scenario individually for possible one character savings is just not worth it", that is a valid argument.

Comment: I'm more fan of judge each scenario individually, that could mark the difference that I wanted to hear. Thank You!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yes. `==` is useful wherever type coercion is specifically desired. Otherwise, it should not be used in preference of explicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

The question I would ask your coworker is why someone would go through all the trouble of creating an object with an appropriate `toString` method, then **not** want it to compare equal to `'final'`?  In other words, *why* would not being the same type be a problem if the values are semantically equivalent?  Certainly no one is going to write code like his counter-example by accident.

In my opinion, using strict comparison when it isn't needed violates the [open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).  It shuts down potential avenues of extension.  Not using a feature of a language for the sake of "consistency" is ridiculous.  You don't write `i += 1` instead of `i++` so you can be consistent with `i += 2`.  By all means, be consistent where the situations are the same, but don't be a slave to superficial consistency when the situations differ.

Most people think of the OCP in terms of classes, but it also applies to functions.  In general, it means to minimize the amount of code that will need to change when you add functionality to your program.  In other words, prefer adding code to changing code.

99% of the time, you should be comparing two values of the same type, and those times where comparing different types is required should be blindingly obvious and intentional.  If you have no idea whether `someValue` is a string or not, you have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: I love the answers that I'm getting. Definitely I think the same, that there is not reason to use strict comparison when it isn't needed. Thank You!

Comment: The imagined connection to OCP here is just ridiculous. Are these really becoming such buzz words?

Comment: My question was about the "sense", I explained it a lot of times, sense, about why === is useful for that comparison. Until now, nobody talks about an useful case where === is helpful. Your argument is good, because the extra cognitive load required to judge each scenario. I used a lot ===, for null or false or zero, where there are advantages using it(I said that in my post, not sure why you mentioned again in your answer), but for that kind of string there is no "sense"(still nobody demonstrated it, I read arguments nothing to do with my question).

Comment: @DanielAranda sorry to hear that, I have edited my answer

Comment: @DanielAranda I think that maybe 0.1% of all JavaScript developers actually remember all the implicit conversion rules of the abstract equality comparsion (`==`) algorithm as specified in section 11.9.3 of the EcmaScript specification. Moreover, having read the said algorithm several times - I myself forget what happens when quite often and have to go back to the specification. When I see `==` I have to think _why_ the developer used un-strict comparison - that's some of the cognitive load Esailija is talking about. Moreover, I don't see what the OCP has to do with this.

Comment: @Karl I don't understand how the OCP relates to this at all, if anything. I'm a strong proponent of behavioral typing and I think JS gets it right in many cases - the abstract equality comparison algorithm is _not_ one of them. Equal objects should be equal behaviorally in JavaScript and the `==` operator does not enforce this (nor does it enforce `a==b => b==a` for that matter).

Comment: @Benjamin, OCP is not just for classes.  It applies at the function level too.  If you unnecessarily require code at any level to be changed in order to be extended, that's an OCP violation.

Comment: @Esailija I'm being democratic, marking your answer as the answer. Plus the efforts editing.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that is a valid argument "is hard to remember the ECMA rules". That is what I wanted to hear. I was not looking for consistency, as that should be a question for standards. In my question I was being asking for something specific.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Let's break it up a little - I want people who use my modules in code (be they classes, functions, or even just blocks) and want to add functionality to them to add that functionality _on top_ of the existing API while _keeping it consistent_ instead of making any modifications that make the API. Writing code that's easy to extend has _nothing_ to do with a `==` check, if anything - if I have a supertype and a subtype that overrides toStrings to hack around the language spec I can easily break the LSP for instance. I'd love to hear an actual use case for using `==` for OCP.

Comment: I like your new last paragraph but it completely negates the paragraphs that precede it. First - you argue that using strict comparison might violate OCP because it somehow makes the code less 'extendable' but then argue that you should be aware of exactly what your comparison code does (which makes perfect sense - you should always know what your code does, and you want to compare types that are the same in 99.9% of cases and want to be really explicit in that last 0.01%).Don't the two contradict?